# Unable to load assets, despite adding service account key and audio file

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am learning to build `flutter-firebase` app for speech to text using `medical_dictation` model of `google_speech` ^2.2.0 API. I have already created a service account on GCP, enabled speech to text API, and saved API key. I have saved the API key under the root folder of my flutter project as 'assets/test_service_account.json' and the audio file as 'assets/audio/test.wav'. I have also added the path in pubspec.yaml file. But I get this exception:

> FlutterError (Unable to load asset: "assets/service_account_key.json".
> The asset does not exist or has empty data.)

Similar exception I get with regard to 'test.wav'.

Here is my code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:google_speech/google_speech.dart' as gs;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:google_speech/speech_client_authenticator.dart';

String audioFilePath = 'assets/audio/test.wav';

Future<String> transcribeAudio(String audioFilePath) async {
  final serviceAccountData =
      await rootBundle.loadString('assets/service_account_key.json');
  final serviceAccount = ServiceAccount.fromString(serviceAccountData);

  final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/audio/test.wav');
  final audio = data.buffer.asUint8List();

  final config = gs.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding: gs.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    model: gs.RecognitionModel.medical_dictation,
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode: 'en-US',
  );

  final speechToText = gs.SpeechToText.viaServiceAccount(serviceAccount);

  final response = await speechToText.recognize(config, audio);
  final transcript = response.results
      .map((result) => result.alternatives.first.transcript)
      .join(' ');

  return transcript;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  String transcript = await transcribeAudio(audioFilePath);
  print('Transcript: $transcript');
}
```

Comment: Have you added the assets to `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Problem found with the placement of -assets/ and its indentation in pubspec.yaml file. Thanks.